# Anyone can explain to Entity Framework life cycle?

Tags: entity-framework

I was trying to understand abut EF life cycle but not getting any proper answers about it.
Anyone can explain to Entity Framework life cycle?

Comment: There is no "EF life cycle", at least not in the sense of the ASP.NET or MVC lifecycle.  As such, you need to be more clear about what exactly you're asking about.

Comment: Before 2 days I attend an interview, my interviewer asked me  "what is the life cycle of EF?" so I want to trying to understand what going on EF.

Comment: Typically "lifecycle" refers to an execution pipeline, and that doesn't exist in EF.  There are many possible ways to use EF and explaining this would be well beyond the bounds of an SO question.  It's also changed considerably over the years, and depends on whether you're referring to EDMX, or code first versions, DbContext, ObjectContext, etc... There are so many variations that this question would quickly devolve into a massive essay.

Comment: Actually I want to know answers of this question. can you explain about it? What is perfect answers of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't an Entity Framework lifecycle, there is such a thing as an Entity Lifecycle, which I suppose could be confused with an EF Lifecycle.

The Entity Lifecycle describes the process in which an Entity is created, added, modified, deleted, etc...

You can read more about that here:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-lifecycle.aspx

You can also read about it in Chapter 6 of Entity Framework 4 in Action, but beyond that.. that's the closest thing you're going to get.

Comment: Thanks for the clearing my confusion! But I want to know the above answers is behalf of the DbContext mechanism? Because @Imran Ghani(www.entityframeworktutorial.net) explain about EF life cycle behalf of DbContext.